# Atualizar conteúdo da modal dinâmicamente

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Possuo uma tabela com até 10 serviços listados, e cada linha possui um botão de atualizar. Ao clicar no botão atualizar, uma janela modal abre com os dados desta linha, assim como um form para alteração.

Contudo, não consigo fazer com que ao clicar no botão, o controller retorne uma partial view e abra a janela modal com os dados atualizados. Estou utilizando bootstrap para o frontend.

Trecho de Código FrontEnd:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkthis" /></td>
            <td>@item.Chave</td>
            <td id="Nome @item.Chave">@item.Nome</td>
            <td>
                <p>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Atualizar","Servico", new {chave = item.Chave})" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs atualizar" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" data-placement="top" rel="tooltip"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Conforme código acima, preciso que no clique do  preciso abrir uma modal com os dados do serviço da linha.

O código acima apenas acessa o controller e retorna a partial view, mas como posso abrir uma modal a partir disto? É possível com Ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível. Por sinal, existe uma implementação no CodePlex em que isso é feito como uma extensão:

> https://mvcmodaldialog.codeplex.com

Com ele, você pode colocar um link para a sua Modal assim:

```
@Ajax.ModalDialogActionLink("Clique aqui para abrir seu modal", "Dialog1", "Dialog1")
```

[A explicação completa está aqui](http://www.devzest.com/blog/post/ASPNet-MVC-Modal-Dialog.aspx).

Se precisar que eu empacote isso como um NuGet, só me avisar que atualizo a resposta aqui com o pacote.